# ResharperC++ suggests to make method const

Tags: c++, resharper-c++

ResharperC++ suggests to make a class method const even if in the method the data is accessed through members. I know this is legal to make them const, but I was wondering if it is possible to disable this suggestion somehow or even better reverse it, so it issues a suggestion if this method would be declared const.

An example would be

```
void test()
{
    data->myData = 3;
}
```

ResharperC++'s outputs: `Member function may be 'const'`

**P.S.** I also do not want to enter an argument about const-correctness, but would only very much like to know how to make this happen ;)

[image]

Comment: you are not modifiying a member, but only something a member points to, whether this is logically part of the class or not you have to decide

Comment: @user463035818 I am aware of this. I have decided and now I would very much like to modify Resharpers suggestions ;)   I am also aware this might not be possible.

Comment: yeah I had to read the question twice to really understand it ;)

Comment: would be nice if there was some smartpointer whose `const get()` returns a `const T*` then you could make it explicit whether the `const` is supposed to extend to the pointee or not

Comment: [propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) does that.

Comment: if I understood correctly you could use `propagate_const` and then the method no longer can be `const` but it must be non-const

Comment: ...or do you want to keep the code as is and only tweak resharper?

Comment: @user463035818 First I wanted to tweak resharper.... now I will check propagate_const as well ;)

Comment: Looks like propagate_const is an experimantal feature, right? I would prefer the ResharperC++ tweak if there were one.

Comment: cannot be too hard to write a small wrapper that has all you need (basically you only need a `const T* get() const;` to "propagate" the constness)

Comment: @user463035818 I agree, still would be need if there were a solution with Resharper.

Comment: [Disabling/enabling specific code inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#disable)

Comment: @Axalo This is an all or nothing option (at least if you mean the `Member function may be const` flag), as disabling also disables the suggestions were const would be a very good idea.

Comment: @Axalo propagate_const is great!!!! As soon our *$&§$* compiler supports that I will certainly use it! Thanks, I didn't know that existed.

Comment: You don't need compiler support for that, there are implementations online that you can use until it becomes standard.

Comment: @Axalo Any idea were to find an Implementation?

Comment: Yes, [here](https://github.com/jbcoe/propagate_const/blob/master/propagate_const.h).

Comment: @Axalo Great, thanks. Are you aware that modifying the std-namespace may rsult in UB? So simply using this implementation may not be such a good idea.

Comment: @user32434999  I believe you can change the level of warning from "suggestion" to "hint", at least in the last Resharper C++ version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the inspection just for this specific occurrence, you can ask ReSharper to insert a comment which will suppress the inspection. To do that, click "Disable once with comment" in the inspection submenu of the `Alt+Enter` context menu. See [Suppressing code inspections in specific scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#suppress) for details.

Comment: No, its more a general issue